# Is there some notation for "picking up the $n$-th domain/column" of a relation?

Tags: notation, relations

Is there a good/standard notation for the "$n$-th domain/column" of an $m$-ary relation $R$ where $1\leq n\leq m$? If I denote it currently by $\mathrm{dom}_n(R)$, then that means
$$ \mathrm{dom}_n(R) = \{a_n:\exists a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1},a_{n+1},\cdots,a_m\ (a_1,\cdots,a_n,\cdots,a_m)\in R\} $$
So if $$R=\prod_{1\leq i\leq m} A_i$$
then $\mathrm{dom}_n(R)$ would be $A_n$. For a binary relation $R$, $\mathrm{dom}_1(R)=\mathrm{dom}(R)$, and $\mathrm{dom}_2(R)=\mathrm{ran}(R)$.

Comment: [Projection (set theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(set_theory)) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Not exactly, the projection picks out the $n$-th element of a tuple, which belongs to some Cartesian product. What I want is the *set* of all $n$-th elements of tuples in a Cartesian product, or a relation. In other words, $\{\mathrm{proj}_n(t):t\in R\}$.

Comment: Define the "big-proj": $\text{Proj}_n(R)= \{ \ldots \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Of course one could/should give a definition first in the context, I was just asking about if there exists already some standard notation, or some notation that is popular (well, it's not so important...)

Comment: See [Projection (relational algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra))

Comment: $\Pi_{i_1,\dots,i_k}(R)$ or $\pi_{i_1,\dots,i_k}(R)$ seems to be used for $\{(a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_k}):\exists \mathbf{a}\in R\text{ such that } \mathbf{a}_{i_j} = a_{i_j}\text{ for } j=1,\dots,k \}$. So in your case you want $\Pi_i(R)$ or $\pi_i(R)$. Apart from the wiki link from @MauroALLEGRANZA, you can also google for, e.g., relational clone, which gets you to the universal algebra literature where those projections are studied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R \subseteq \prod\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} A_i$, then let $\pi_i : \prod\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} A_i \to A_i$ denote the $i$th projection map. Then you're referring to $\pi_i(R)$. It's also often written as $\exists_{\pi_i} R$.